# Retrieving last modified time in OSX Bash script

Tags: macos, bash

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm new to Bash scripting and my Google skills are failing me. I am trying to write a script that ultimately will examine the last modified time for every file in a directory, and if a file was last modified > 3 days ago, then compress the file with gzip. I can currently print out the last modified time with my script here:

```
  1 !#/bin/bash
  2 echo "Enter directory"
  3 
  4 read directory
  5 
  6 for entry in "$directory"/*
  7 do
  8      stat -f "%Sm" "$entry"
  9 done
```

This prints out the times just fine:

```
Randalls-MacBook-Pro:bash_scripts randallbanks$ ./print_last_modified.sh 
./print_last_modified.sh: line 1: !#/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Enter directory
..
Apr  6 13:12:21 2015
Apr 19 18:50:26 2015
Apr 14 11:29:06 2015
Apr  7 12:26:37 2015
Apr 15 16:05:17 2015
Apr  6 16:28:06 2015
Apr  6 12:28:40 2015
Apr  6 12:28:40 2015
Apr  6 12:28:40 2015
Apr  6 12:28:40 2015
Apr 23 17:03:03 2015
```

But what I'm having trouble figuring out is how to store or parse these in such a way that I can check if their last modified time was > 3 days ago. How can I go about this?

Edit: bonus question: What is up with it apparently not recognizing my shebang in the header?

Comment: Mnemonic solution: shebang is short for hash bang where `#` is hash and `!` is bang.  Thus, a shebang is `#!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gzip files that were last modified 3 or more days ago, use:

```
find "$directory" -mtime +2 -type f -exec gzip {} \;
```

If your `find` is modern enough, use:

```
find "$directory" -mtime +2 -type f -exec gzip {} +
```

#### How it works

- `find "$directory"`

  This starts `find` looking for files in the directory tree under `$directory`.
- `-mtime +2`

  This looks for files that were modified more than 2 days old.  (More than 2 means three or more).  See `man find` for details on how `find` computes age rounded to days.
- `-type f`

  This restricts `find` to looking for regular files.
- `-exec gzip {} \;`

  This tells `find` to `gzip` the files that it finds.

Comment: Could I ask you what exactly the '+2' parameter is doing? I am trying to modify this for testing purposes to check for files that are greater than say 2 minutes old

EDIT: Just saw your edit. Thanks!

Comment: @RandyBanks By the way, if you want age in minutes, you can use `-mtime`.  So, `-mtime +2`  would mean _more than_ two minutes old.

Answer (score 1):

Your shebang is a bangshe. It should be `#!`; it is `!#`.

The `find` command on OS X (and BSDs, generally) can do what you're looking for. The `-newermt` checks the modification time against a time specified in a string, including such strings as `"3 days ago"`.

So:

```
find . -not -newermt "3 days ago" -exec gzip {} \;
```

Comment: Haha... duh. Thanks Ken!